# Full-Width header (or footer) & Content

Tags: html

I would like a header which spans the whole width of the page, while the content is limited in width, much like the bar at the top of this stackoverflow page.

I could use:

```
<header>
    <div id="contents">
        blah blah
    </div>
</header>
```

or I could use:

```
<div id="contents">
    <header>
        blah blah
    </header>
</div>
```

Is there one which would be preferable from a semantic point of view?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From a semantic point of view ... does your content container really need to be either a parent or child of your header - could they not be siblings? Also, if you are interested in semantics, I would look at using the **section** tag for your content container instead of a *div* with *id=content*. So, I would imagine something like this:

```
<header>...</header>
<section>...</section>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp